# How do you factor covariates into your hidden markov model?

Tags: python, hidden-markov-model

I am currently implementing a Hidden Markov Model in Python and would like to add covariates to my model. There are 2 categorical covariates each covariate can take up to 4 values. For each combination of covariates, I am expecting to see different (A,B,Pi) combination of parameters. I would really appreciate it if someone can help me with the initial skeleton.

Answer (score 1):

Covariates can be added either to the transition probability or the emission probability (or state dependency matrix) or both. How and why you want to add covariates depends on your functional/domain knowledge of the problem as well as intuition. I could learn a lot about the basics of HMM from [this](https://www.crcpress.com/Hidden-Markov-Models-for-Time-Series-An-Introduction-Using-R/Zucchini-MacDonald/9781584885733) book by Zuccini MacDonald. There are a few papers that you may want to search on google scholar that use covariates in HMM such as [this](http://stat.wharton.upenn.edu/~dsmall/hmm_alcohol_accepted_paper.pdf). The authors of HMM with R are coming up with a new edition that includes text on how to include covariates.

Hope this helps for a starting point.